# Anime movie about two brothers, made around 2005-2015

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

The movie starts with one of the brothers that I will call Jorge (not an actual name) falling from a cliff while fighting a devilish person with third eye in the jungle. After waking up he needs to fight a big crocodile; after defeating the croc, a kid saves him and brings him to his house, where he is living with his sister, to heal. After that the other brother (John) starts searching for him. Jorge fights to defend the family who helped him survive and saves a man or more from execution, but John became devilish and fights with Jorge. I remember there was a lake who made him devilish or after fighting a demon. At the end they became united and defeat the demon and Jorge gets married with the girl who saved him.

Comment: I tried to clean up your question a bit, but I got a bit confused about who was fighting who or marrying who. I don't suppose you could clarify? If it helps, you can state something at the beginning along the lines of "I'll call the one brother Hans and the other brother Franz. Hans falls off a cliff at the beginning..."